# ISA 2006 Ent with NLB configuration

Tags: local-area-network, vmware-vsphere

We have created to virtual machines and installed ISA 2006 Ent and enable NLB configuration, each machine has two NIC one connected to LAN and other connected to DMZ, we are not able to ping DMZ subnet IP of ISA from another machine which is on same DMZ subnet even though we have diable the all ISA services (including firewall). But we can ping LAN IP from all our internal subnets and this ping is working with ISA services are started or stop status

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Check out the System Firewall policy, where the default setting is to not allow ICMP into the ISA server except from specific management computers...